# Javafx Slider Thumb

Tags: java, javafx, slider

Is there a way to display an integer on the slider thumb in javafx? Just curious because I am trying to make a clean UI and cannot find anything on displaying an integer on the slider thumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to address the requirement is by accessing the thumb node and include a Text/Label node. Please check the below demo for what i mean.

You can adjust the thumb padding and the text size for fine tuning.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderTextDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Slider slider = new Slider(1, 10, 3);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(1f);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(1f);
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);

        Text text = new Text();
        slider.skinProperty().addListener((obs,old,skin)->{
            if(skin!=null){
                StackPane thumb = (StackPane)slider.lookup(".thumb");
                thumb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                thumb.getChildren().add(text);
            }
        });
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs,old,val)->text.setText(val.intValue()+""));
        slider.setValue(2);

        VBox root = new VBox(slider);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setSpacing(20);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Slider Text Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to rely on accessing the skin,you can indeed implement/initialize the Slider as below. That way you can create a custom Slider and can reuse in multiple places.

```
Slider slider = new Slider(1, 10, 3) {
    Text text;

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();
        if (text == null) {
            text = new Text(((int) getValue()) + "");
            valueProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> text.setText(val.intValue() + ""));
            StackPane thumb = (StackPane) lookup(".thumb");
            thumb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            thumb.getChildren().add(text);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just to note: The above implicitly relies on the skin of the `Slider` to be the default skin.

Comment: Updated my answer w.r.t relying on skin.

Comment: That still implicitly relies on the default skin. It's the skin that adds the `StackPane` used as the thumb and gives it the `.thumb` style class. I'm not necessarily saying that's a problem, especially not if the OP continues to use the default skins (assuming what's in the _JavaFX CSS Reference Guide_ is considered public and stable API, though note that only says `.thumb` is a `Region`). But if the OP were to use a library that replaces the skin with its own implementation then the above code could break.

Comment: I believe if he is ever going to use his own skin implementation, that would make things more straight forward, that he has full control of all the internals and can customize the Slider as he like.

Comment: @slaw, Sorry I overlooked the word "library" in your comment. And I agree with you that the implementation may change if the skin has different approach of building the thumb node. Thanks :)