# How could I make a slider like this? Could this even be executed as a slider, or do I need another kind of node for this?

Tags: java, javafx, slider, javafx-8

The kind of Slider I would want to use:

[image]

Is this possible or do I need another kind of Node to execute this? Is this even possible in JavaFX?

I haven't tried anything yet, but it's kind of hard to find information about customizing sliders

Comment: Also consider [`Pagination`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76359690/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A control that has buttons to increment or decrement a value is a [`Spinner`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html). The [CSS documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#spinner) shows how to modify the position of the increment and decrement buttons.

Here is a quick demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SpinnerDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(1, 10, 1);
        spinner.getStyleClass().add("split-arrows-horizontal");
        spinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("Song "+newValue+" selected"));
        spinner.setEditable(false);

        VBox controls = new VBox(5, spinner, new Label("Select Song"));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(controls, 400 ,400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]

Further styling can be achieved in the usual way with CSS. For example, applying this stylesheet

```CSS
.spinner.split-arrows-horizontal .text-field {
    -fx-pref-column-count: 5;
}

.spinner,
.spinner .text-field,
.spinner .increment-arrow-button,
.spinner .decrement-arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
}


.spinner .increment-arrow-button:hover,
.spinner .decrement-arrow-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-background, -3%);
}

.spinner .increment-arrow-button:pressed,
.spinner .decrement-arrow-button:pressed {
    -fx-background: -fx-pressed-base;
}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: I think the OP needs to do more explaining. When I think about sliders, I think about controls similar to [`Slider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html). This leads me to think the OP wants the thumb of the slider to look like the image posted.

Comment: @SedJ601 I interpreted *"do I need another kind of node to do this"* to mean the OP was not sure which kind of control implemented what they were looking for.

Comment: you may be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I am confused about if you are looking for a `Spinner` or a `Slider`. James D posted a `Spinner` answer. This is a `Slider` answer.

Altered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66995911/2423906).

```
mport javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.antdesignicons.AntDesignIconsFilled;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Slider slider = new Slider(1, 10, 3);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(1f);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(1f);
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);

        
        Text text = new Text();
        FontIcon fiCaretLeft = new FontIcon(AntDesignIconsFilled.CARET_LEFT);
        FontIcon fiCaretRight = new FontIcon(AntDesignIconsFilled.CARET_RIGHT);
        HBox thumbRoot = new HBox(fiCaretLeft, text, fiCaretRight);
        thumbRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        slider.skinProperty().addListener((obs,old,skin)->{
            if(skin!=null){
                StackPane thumb = (StackPane)slider.lookup(".thumb");
                thumb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                thumb.getChildren().add(thumbRoot);
            }
        });
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs,old,val)->text.setText(val.intValue()+""));
        slider.setValue(2);

        VBox root = new VBox(slider);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setSpacing(20);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Slider Text Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the `lookup()` call?

Comment: @DaveB, I don't think there is a way.

Comment: @DaveB not without writing a custom skin. I don't this is what the OP is looking for, though. The content of the thumb seems redundant. (The arrows don't do anything and the label just replicates the values in the tick labels.)